# Scaling of neural networks

Tags: network

In general, how does the functionality of a neural network scale as the amount of processing power is increased? For example, it seems reasonable that on certain tasks a "division of labor" can double the speed of response if twice the power is used. Is this true generally?

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right SE to post that question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Computer Science, not EE.

Answer (score 1):

Conventional neural networks are feed-forward only; response time is proportional to the number of layers in the network. Adding more neurons horizontally will not speed it up and may slow it down.

Comment: Yet in some cases one can split the data between two networks. In which case doubling the capacity halves the search time

Comment: You're going to have to define what you mean by "search time" here: is this some scenario where you're presenting a corpus of e.g images to a neural network and optimising for time to first match?

Answer (score 1):

In general, a Neural Network is sized to  achieve an objective such as accuracy, precision, recall etc. that's related to the machine learning task. When increasing or reducing the hidden layer size you would be more concerned about variance, bias etc. than power and speed.

Sometimes multiple NNs are used; e.g. in a multiclass classification problem, but usually because that improves the measure of performance on the task. In a realtime application it may be helpful to prioritse the speed of the  Neural network, but this would be a secondary concern to the performance of the task.